# Client Java Time Delay User Input

Tags: java

how can i end a client program in java if there is no user input for 2 minutes? please help
am using threading to create multiple clients
Each client program should end if there is no input from command line(not using GUI)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you checked documentation for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html ,https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could have a field

```
long lastInputTime;
```

that represents the last time there was any input in the program. After that, during your main loop, do

```
long timeSinceLastInput = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastInputTime;    
long threshold = 120000;

if (timeSinceLastInput >= threshold) {
    System.exit(0); // You should prefer exiting gracefully here
}
```

And then, in the method that is processing user input, just add

```
this.lastInputTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

to update the value.

Comment: but how to i get the lastInputTime? really confused with this

Comment: Take a look at the last code block. I'm guessing that you have some kind of Scanner, or InputReader to check for user input. At the end of that method (or loop), add the last code block. That way, whenever the program DOES read some sort of input from the user, it will update the lastInputTime field.

Comment: thanks a lot. really helpful. but one last clarification.. i want this.lastInputTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); to be updated only when user enters a input.. but how do i check if user has entered a input or not?